# Server migration to all new hardware

Tags: server, 18.04, migration

I have a ubuntu server on an old i5-650 machine and I'm building a new ryzen 2600 server.  I've got ubuntu 18.04 working on the old machine now.  My question is can I just take an image of the old machines os hd and image it to the new hd and boot the new server without issues?

Comment: You can sure try, and maybe you will get lucky. Many folks run into problems imaging to new hardware.

Comment: Well I tried it and was an instant kernel panic when it tried to boot. Luckily it wasn't too bad installing a new instance of Ubuntu server.  My biggest concern was moving my mdadm raid5 array and the new machine being able to read it.  This was actually painless as mdadm scan found it.  The UUID from for the array was the same as it was on the old machine so it was a copy and paste from the fstab of the old machine to the new machine.